# Equation of motion for cyclic model of the universe

Tags: cosmology, lagrangian-formalism, cosmological-inflation

I recently started to study the cyclic universe. I came across this [article](http://www.physics.princeton.edu/%7Esteinh/sciencecyc.pdf) [1]. My question is about the action used for describing the cyclic model:
$$S = \int d^{4}x\sqrt{-g}(\frac{1}{16\pi G}R-\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^{2}-V(\phi)+\beta ^{4}(\phi)(\rho _{M}+\rho _{R}))$$
where $R$ is Ricci scalar and $g$ is the metric.
I solve the Euler-Lagrange equation for this action and find the equation of motion for $\phi$:
$$\partial _{\mu }\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _{\mu }\phi )} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial _{\mu }\phi } = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow \partial _{\mu }\left [ \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-g} g^{\alpha \beta }\left ( \delta _{\mu }^{\alpha } \partial _{\beta }\phi + \delta _{\mu }^{\beta }\partial _{\alpha}\phi \right )\right ] = \sqrt{-g}\left ( -V_{,\phi }+4\beta ^{3} \beta _{,\phi }(\rho _{M}+\rho _{R})\right )$$
The radiation term is independent of $\phi$ so only $\rho _{M}$ enters the equation of motion. The zero component:
$$3 a^{2} \dot{a} \dot{\phi } + a^{3}\ddot{\phi }=a^{3}(-V_{,\phi }+4 \beta ^{3}\beta _{,\phi }\rho _{M})$$
$$\Rightarrow\ddot{\phi }+3H\dot{\phi }= -V_{,\phi }+4 \beta ^{3}\beta _{,\phi }\rho _{M}$$
where $H$ is the Hubble parameter.
But this result is different from what was written in the article. The difference is the coefficient of the last term. In addition, I have a problem finding Friedmann equations for this action (again in finding coefficients). Can anybody elaborate on the reason?

**Reference:**

[1] P.J. Steinhardt and N. Turok, *"A Cyclic Model of the Universe,"* Science 296 (2002), available at [here](http://www.physics.princeton.edu/%7Esteinh/sciencecyc.pdf)

Comment: For the problem of the factor $4$, from the equation $(5)$ (fluid equation of motion), you see that there is a dependence $\rho_M \sim \hat a^{-3}\sim (a\beta(\phi))^{-3}$, so the term $\beta^4(\phi)\rho_m$ is (secretely...) proportionnal to $\beta(\phi)$

Comment: Thanks very much, @Trimok. That explains the factor 4, but what about the sign? I read this [article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0307132v4.pdf). In this paper the sign of the coupling term is negative. Which one is correct?

Comment: It is not completely clear for me what $(\partial \phi)^2$ is exactly. If it is $(\partial \phi)^2 = -(\partial_0 \phi)^2+(\vec \partial \phi)^2$, then the Euler-Lagrange equations give a $\square \phi =  \ddot \phi - \triangle\phi$, and not a $\ddot  \phi$. So, I think you need to reexpress, if possible, $\triangle\phi$ as a function of $\beta, \beta_{,\phi}$, etc...

Comment: I think that $\triangle\phi$ is zero and $\phi$ only depends on time @Trimok.

Comment: Seems strange. You have $2$ papers with same authors (J. Steinhardt and Neil Turok) and a different sign... Sounds like a typo for the equation ($1$) of the first [paper](http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~steinh/sciencecyc.pdf).